# Show div base on onchange from dropdown option, help

Tags: javascript, css, html, show, onchange

I try to show some information inside of `<div>` as following:

```
    <div id="show_details" style="'display:block;' : 'display:none;'"> SHOW me
    </div>
```

by choose from drop down option e.g.

```
         <?php if ($books == 'art') { ?>
          <option value="art" selected="selected" id="art_indicator" onchange="(this.selected) ? $('#show_details').css('display','block') : $('#show_details').css('display','none');">Art</option>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <option value="art" id="art_indicator" onchange="(this.selected) ? $('#show_details').css('display','block') : $('#show_details').css('display','none');">Art</option>
          <?php } ?>
```

and the full code as following,

```
    <tr>
      <td>Book Option</td>
      <td>
      <select name="books">
        <?php  foreach ($others as $other) { ?>
          <?php if ($other == $other['other']) { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $other['other']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $other['title']; ?></option>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $other['other']; ?>"><?php echo $other['title']; ?></option>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php } ?>

          <?php if ($books == 'art') { ?>
          <option value="art" selected="selected" id="art_indicator" onchange="(this.selected) ? $('#show_details').css('display','block') : $('#show_details').css('display','none');">Art</option>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <option value="art" id="art_indicator" onchange="(this.selected) ? $('#show_details').css('display','block') : $('#show_details').css('display','none');">Art</option>
          <?php } ?>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
    <div id="show_details" style="'display:block;' : 'display:none;'"> SHOW me
    </div>
```

Is there some way to fix this?

Comment: Are you just trying to show the contents of `#show_details` whenever anything is selected? Or is its contents supposed to change based on what is selected?

Comment: @Michael I am trying to show content of `<div> #show_details` when ever `<option value="art" id="art_indicator"`only selected, thanks

Comment: !omc11 Got it - I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function showDiv()
{
  // hide any showing
  $(".details_div").each(function(){
      $(this).css('display','none');
  });

  // our target
  var target = "#details_" + $("#test_select").val();                                                                                                                                

  // does it exist?
  if( $(target).length > 0 )
  {
    // show it
    $(target).css('display','block');
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){

  // bind it
  $("#test_select").change(function(){
    showDiv();
  });

  // run it automagically
  showDiv();
});


</script>
<style>
.details_div
{
  display:none;
}
</style>
{/literal}

<select id="test_select">
  <option value="">- Select - </option>
  <option value="book" selected="selected">Books</option>
  <option value="movie">Movie</option>
</select>

<div id="details_book" class="details_div">BOOK DETAILS</div>
<div id="details_movie" class="details_div">MOVIE DETAILS</div>
```

Comment: @Josh, it's look very nice and more details, I appreciate it, so I will try this also and come to you with report. thanks

Comment: @omc11: No problem, you should be able to drop it in a .html file and run it, obviously making sure you include jQuery at the top. Once it works you can wrap PHP around the skeleton. Just note the divs have a specific naming convention.

Comment: @Josh, now I have the result, it's work fine whenever i go to `<div id="details_book" class="details_div">BOOK DETAILS</div>` but when ever it as selected (mean after saved it then page refreshed) it disapear, and i want it appear when ever as selected, thanks

Comment: @omc11: I've updated it, be sure to make sure your PHP populates the selected="selected" accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using jquery so I would first suggest to remove all javascript from the html / php and put it in a separate section or file.

You can then simply do stuff like:

```
$("#art_indicator").change(function() {
  // do what you want to do  
});
```

Also, the html for `#show_details` seems to be wrong:

```
style="'display:block;' : 'display:none;'"
```

is no valid style declaration.

Comment: nah.. that's it perhaps my bad, but please let me know the coorect of style declaration of `style="'display:block;' : 'display:none;'"` thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `<option>` registers the `onchange` event.  What you want instead is to use its parent `<select onchange=''>` to define the change event.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function selOnChange() {
    if ($('#selectList').value == "art" {
      $("#show_details").css('display', 'block');
    } else {
      $("#show_details").css('display', 'none');
    }
  }
```

Now you need to have a default "unselected" option. I have it here with value="-1"
When the select list changes, if its value is the value of `#art_indicator`, the div will be shown.  otherwise, the div will not be shown.

```
<select id='selectList' name="books" onchange="selOnChange()">
  <option value="-1">Select something</option>
  <option id="#art_indicator" value="art">Art choice...</option>
  <?php // list all your other options ?>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks for this, I will try it first and i will come when ever i have the result.

Comment: Yeah... but the value of that I want to show div content is `art` not `-1`, e.g. `<option value="art">Select something</option>' so when ever i go to `value='art'` or is as selected then the content should be visible otherwise invisible, thanks